# What's the best way to create a user turnable wheel in HTML5/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create a wheel which will be dragged around 360 degrees by the user (in order to have a specific segment of the wheel placed at the top).

I've found examples of a roulette wheel using HTML5 canvas which just spin an image of a wheel for a random amount of time. However, when it comes to allowing a user to drag a wheel as they wish, I'm stumped.

I'd also rather make the wheel from HTML/CSS rather than use an image, because it needs to be dynamically updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mmm this looks like a math problem...

so define a center point and then use trigonometry to define the angle of the line (from the center point to the mouse) from the horizon

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry

now draw in a canvas on the center point inside the cnavas the weel, get the angle and redraw the weel as needed

Answer (score 1):

The [Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/) drawing framework allows you to just about do anything that you might have seen done in flash - but without flash. It works in just about all browsers without plugins. It uses SVG or VML depending on the browser. Have a look at the draggable tiger example [here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/draw/Tiger.html)

**Edit:**

Documentation for the drawing framework which is part of the larger ExtJS framework is found at: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.draw.Component

This is the code I knocked up for a draggable circle/wheel. Didn't put any spinning action in as I think you've got that worked out.

```
<script src="ext-all-debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Ext.onReady( function() {

            //create the drawing surface
            var drawComponent = Ext.create('Ext.draw.Component', {
                width: 400,
                height: 400,
                draggable: {
                    constrain: true,
                    constrainTo: Ext.getBody()
                },
                autoShow:true,
                floating: true,
                renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                items:[{
                    //add the circle sprite to the
                    //drawing surface
                    type: 'circle',
                    fill: '#79BB3F',
                    "stroke-width": "1",
                    stroke: "#000",
                    radius: 100,
                    x: 100,
                    y: 100
                }]

            });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Having trouble finding that drawing framework on their site or Google. Their products seem to paid for. Is it free? If so, where is it? Sorry!

Comment: @samiles The drawing framework is part of their overall javascript framework Ext JS (http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/download?page=a). It is free to download and is open source. Their is a commercial license as well - but it would be up to you to decide if you need to buy one of those

Comment: Documentation for the drawing part of the ExtJS framework is at: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.draw.Component

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use probably Canvas to draw: http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html

For dragging the wheel you will need to handle mouse down, mouse move and mouse up events.